# Different goodness-of-fit statistics for same model fit as GLM and linear mixed model - why?

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, matlab, model-comparison

When I fit a simple linear model such as `y ~ 1 + x1 + x2` in MATLAB R2018a or R2017a, the `fitglm()` and `fitglme()` functions return the same coefficients. However, the two functions return radically different goodness of fit (model comparison) statistics:

```
%% generate data
rng(0); data_size = [100 1];

y0 = rand(data_size); y = y0 > 0.5; % categorical response variable
x1 = y0 + rand(data_size); % predictor 1 (correlated)
x2 = rand(data_size); % predictor 2 (uncorrelated)

data = table(y,x1,x2);

%% fit the model
mspec = 'y ~ 1 + x1 + x2'; % simple linear model, no random variables
glm = fitglm(data,mspec,'Distribution','binomial','Link','logit');
lme = fitglme(data,mspec,'Distribution','binomial','Link','logit');

% confirm model fits are the same
disp(glm.Coefficients.Estimate); disp(lme.Coefficients.Estimate);

% however...
fprintf('glm deviance: %.2f, lme deviance: %.2f\n',glm.Deviance,lme.ModelCriterion.Deviance);
fprintf('glm AIC: %.2f, lme AIC: %.2f\n',glm.ModelCriterion.AIC,lme.ModelCriterion.AIC);
```

This returns identical coefficients, but very different deviance and AIC values:

```
glm deviance: 98.22, lme deviance: 469.27
glm AIC: 104.22, lme AIC: 475.27
```

Is there some difference in how goodness-of-fit statistics are computed in a GLM and (assumed) linear mixed model? I expected that since there aren't actually any random effects in my linear mixed model, the outputs should be the same.

Comment: I'd appreciate a suggestion from the moderators on why this question is at risk of being off-topic. I edited it to emphasize the more general issue (are deviance, AIC, etc. computed differently in a GLM vs a lme model), hope that helps.

Comment: I think that helps. It can be difficult to tell if there's a statistical question underlying one that's superficially about software & code.

Comment: AIC and Deviance are generally not used to infer anything about goodness of fit, rather the differences between AIC or Deviance for two or more models is used. For this reason the AIC or Deviance reported by different software or methods can vary by an additive constant